# Retryable DataSource is not working with Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I am creating Spring MVC project and have neo4j datasource. When i am trying to create Retrybale data source on getConnection getting issue;

'''Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: DataSource router not initialized
at org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:201) ~[spring-core-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.lookup.AbstractRoutingDataSource.determineTargetDataSource(AbstractRoutingDataSource.java:225) ~[spring-jdbc-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]'''

public class RetryableDatabasePostProcessor implements BeanPostProcessor {

```
@Override
public Object postProcessBeforeInitialization(Object bean, String beanName) throws BeansException {
    if(bean instanceof DataSource) {
        return new RetryableDataSource((DataSource) bean);
    }
    return bean;
}

@Override
public Object postProcessAfterInitialization(Object bean, String beanName) throws BeansException {
    return bean;
}
```

}

public  class RetryableDataSource extends AbstractDataSource {

```
private DataSource dataSource;

public RetryableDataSource(DataSource bean) {
    dataSource = bean;
}

@Override
@Retryable(value= {CustomRetryException.class}, maxAttemptsExpression = "2",  backoff = @Backoff(delayExpression = "2000"))
public Connection getConnection() throws SQLException {
    return getConnectionWithRetry();
}

@Override
@Retryable(value= {CustomRetryException.class}, maxAttemptsExpression = "2",  backoff = @Backoff(delayExpression = "2000"))
public Connection getConnection(String username, String password) throws SQLException {
    return getConnectionWithRetry();
}


private Connection getConnectionWithRetry() {
    try {
        return dataSource.getConnection();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        if(CheckExceptionUtil.isRetryableException(e) ){
            throw  new CustomRetryException(e.getMessage());
        }
        throw new ApiException(e);
    }

}
```

}